# How can I train my SVM to predict the outcome of the match?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

At the moment I have a DataFrame using pandas with 30 features and 30 rows. the features are `['home_team_goals_difference' 'away_team_goals_difference' 'games_won_home_team' 'games_won_away_team' 'games_against_won' 'games_against_lost' 'League_24558.0' 'home_player_1_overall_rating'...'home_player_11_overall_rating'
 'away_player_1_overall_rating'...'away_player_11_overall_rating' 'label']` all the values are floats.

`label` is either Win = 1, Draw = 0 or Lose = -1

I'm trying to train Sklearn's svm.SVC, but I'm not sure how to `.fit()` the data in order to predict either Win, Draw or Lose according to all the other features.

I've looked at Sklearn tutorials but they use dataset.data and dataset.target and I don't know what the equivalent of this would be with my data.

```
clf = svm.SVC(gamma=0.001)
x = inputs[:-1]
y = inputs.loc[:,'label'][:-1]
clf.fit(x,y)
print("Prediction:", clf.predict(PCAinput[-1]))
```

This is what I'm trying. `x` is the whole DataFrame and `y` is the `label`. PCAinput is the DataFrame but without `label`. `label` is the tag either Win, Draw or Lose.

I believe the issue is the format I'm giving `x` and `y`, but I don't know how to make it into the correct input format.

Comment: [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  Show us how you've set up the data so far: give us code that requires only 2-5 lines of help (and your best shot so far), and you're more likely to get that help.

Comment: BTW, it likely won't be me -- I use MLlib and Trusted Analytics; I'm not particularly versed in SciKit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue, it works when `x` is a DataFrame without the `label` and `y` has to be of type pandas.core.series.Series, which is obtained by doing inputs['label']. so This is what I end up with.

```
X = PCAinput          #pandas DataFrame without 'label'
y = inputs['label']   #pandas Series only the labels
clf = svm.SVC()
clf.fit(X,y)
```

with this I can now do:

```
clf.predict(PCAinput)
```

and returns:

```
['Defeat', 'Defeat', 'Defeat', 'Win', 'Draw', 'Defeat', 'Win',
   'Defeat', 'Defeat', 'Win', 'Win', 'Defeat', 'Win', 'Draw', 'Defeat',
   'Defeat', 'Win', 'Defeat', 'Win', 'Defeat', 'Win', 'Win', 'Win',
   'Win', 'Draw', 'Draw', 'Win', 'Defeat', 'Win', 'Win']
```